# Add Percentage Sign in Table in R

Tags: r

How do I add percentage sign to this table?
`table(sample.1$Department)/50*100`

[image]

I want to add the percentage sign to the numbers here. E.g. 28%, 46%, 8%, etc.

Comment: It's better if you embed the output in the question, instead of using a screenshot. It makes it easier for (present and future) people to make sense of your question

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `proportions(table(.))` instead of calculating the percentages manually which is prone to mistakes. Try one of those:

```
with(sample.1, as.data.frame.table(proportions(table(Department))*100)) |>
  transform(Freq=paste0(Freq, '%'))
#   Department Freq
# 1   Facility  10%
# 2       Fire  28%
# 3     Police  46%
# 4     Public   8%
# 5    Special   8%

with(sample.1, proportions(table(Department))*100) |> 
  {\(.) setNames(paste0(., '%'), unlist(attr(., 'dimnames')))}()
# Facility     Fire   Police   Public  Special 
#    "10%"    "28%"    "46%"     "8%"     "8%"
```

**Note: R >= 4.1 used.**

---

*Data:*

```
sample.1 <- data.frame(Department=unlist(Map(rep, c('Fire', 'Police','Public',  'Facility', 'Special'),
                                  c(14, 23, 4, 5,  4))))
```

Comment: This is the better approach. However, I am not a big fan of the `transform()` in the first solution though as it's supposed to be used interactively

Answer (score 1):

### Recreating data

I didnt see a reproducible dataset, so I created one for now:

```
# Create rows and columns:
names <- c("Boston Fire Department",
           "Boston Police Department",
           "Boston Public Library",
           "BPS Facility Management",
           "BPS Special Education")
counts <- c(28,46,8,10,8)

# Turn into data frame:
df <- data.frame(names,
                 counts)
```

### Get proportions/percentages:

From there you will just need to create a new column for the percentages, here thus called "props":

```
df$prop <- paste(df$counts, "%", sep = "")
df
```

Which will print this:

```
                     names counts prop
1   Boston Fire Department     28  28%
2 Boston Police Department     46  46%
3    Boston Public Library      8   8%
4  BPS Facility Management     10  10%
5    BPS Special Education      8   8%
```

Or if you just wanna change the counts to percentages, you can save over the column already there:

```
df$counts <- paste(df$counts, "%", sep = "")
df
```

Which gives you this:

```
                    names counts
1   Boston Fire Department    28%
2 Boston Police Department    46%
3    Boston Public Library     8%
4  BPS Facility Management    10%
5    BPS Special Education     8%
```

Answer (score 1):

The object class from `table()` is a bit obnoxious to work with, unfortunately.

Here is an example using the data from the package `palmerpenguins`:

```
library(palmerpenguins)

t <- table(penguins$species)/50*100
```

```
> t

   Adelie Chinstrap    Gentoo 
      304       136       248
```

```
t2 <- sub("$", "%", t)
names(t2) <- names(t)
```

```
> t2
   Adelie Chinstrap    Gentoo 
   "304%"    "136%"    "248%"
```

What `sub()` does here is to match the regex for the end of the element in the table (i.e., `$`) and to add "%" at the end. Unfortunately, this doesn't keep the header of the table, but it transforms it into a vector with the same order, so we can just overwrite it using `names()`

Comment: This does change the class from `table` to a character vector, though, not sure if it matters at all for your issue.